# How to use an expression with a generic

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, lambda, expression

Here's a class

```
public class Repository<T>
{
  T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition);
}
```

And then in another class that takes a generic type argument I have something like:

```
repo = new Repository<TEntity>();
repo.GetSingle(x=> x.Id == 1); 
// That won't compile because TEntity is a generic type. 
//Compiler doesn't know if TEntity has Id or not.
```

So, how to pass that expression?

UPD: Creating a type constraint class seems to be reasonable solution. But unfortunately doesn't work for me. TEntity in my case is an Entity Framework's EntityObject. Even If I try to create a constraint class and derived it from EntityObject or StructuralObject, compiler says: There is no implicit reference conversion

Comment: Can you add the code definition for TEntity?

Answer (score 3):

Declare "another class" with a type constraint in `TEntity` like:

```
class AnotherClass<TEntity> where TEntity : ISomethingWithId
```

where `ISomethingWithId` could be

```
interface ISomethingWithId {
   int Id {get;}
}
```

Then it should work...

Comment: Now I need something that would work if TEntity is derived from System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface IEntity  as

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    long Id{get; set;}
}
```

and then change the Repository class definition to

```
public class Repository<T> : where T:IEntity
{
     T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition); 
}
```

Ofcourse make sure **TEntity** implements **IEntity**  interface and now your code would compile and work.

Answer (score 2):

If TEntity is a generic type, but you know that any class passed in will have an Id property, you can add a type constraint on the generic class.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id;
}

public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id;
}

public class Test<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity // generic type constraint
{
    private void test()
    {
        var repo = new Repository<TEntity>();
        repo.GetSingle(x => x.Id == 1);
    }
}
```